# Difference between &(*similarObject) and similarObject? Are they not same?

Tags: c++, dynamic, casting

Can someone please explain this to me

```
dynamic_cast<SomeObject *>( &(*similarObject) );
```

What is the point of doing the address of a dereferenced pointer?  Wouldn’t the pointer itself just be the address of it?

Comment: Is similarObject a smart pointer?  This technique is sometimes used to get the reference of a raw pointer, when * has been overloaded.

Comment: Are the dereference and address-of operator overloaded perhaps?

Comment: @DanDan: Put this as an answer.

Comment: &* is also known as "unsmart" operator. Parenthesis are unnecessary.

Comment: Is `similarObject` is a null pointer, this invokes undefined behavior (at least in the current standard). Also, if `similarObject` is a shared pointer or something like that, you introduce a potential leak (there is `dynamic_pointer_cast` for this use). Also `someObject` could be an iterator, not a pointer.

Comment: @DanDan someObject is a user defined class

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It may be that the type of `similarObject` has overloaded `operator*` and so it returns something whose address you're passing to `dynamic_cast`.

`&(*x)` and `x` *may not* be always the same thing. For example, think of iterator:

```
std::map<int, int>::iterator it = v.begin();
```

Then `it` and `&(*it)` are two different thing:

- The type of `it` is `std::map<int, int>::iterator`
- The type of `&(*it)` is `std::pair<int,int>*`

They're *not* at all same. Similar thing may happen with your code-snippet as well.

Comment: I sometimes use `&*v.begin()` instead of `&v[0]` to get a pointer to the beginning of a `std::vector`.

Comment: @Alexandre: In that case, I find `&v[0]` easy to understand, and so I prefer it over `&*v.begin()`.

Comment: I used to find `&v[0]` easier too, but not anymore. Tastes change with time.

Comment: @Alexandre: You mean you used to find `&v[0]` easier, then you got an accident and you started finding it difficult? :P :D

Comment: square brackets are difficult to type on French keyboards, and using `v.begin()` consistantly makes me happy :). The point is that the "`&*` operator" has some use.

Comment: @Alexandre: Hmm.. I see. I didn't know that. I don't know French. Thanks for the info. :-)

Comment: @Alexandre, @Nawaz: I use this form only to get the first item of a `set`, or a similar data structure that does not provide a `[]` or a `front` method. I do not find `[]` that difficult to type, though I do use a French keyboard.

Comment: Also of note is that for any pointer `x`, `x` may be an lvalue, but `&*x` can never be an lvalue.  Though that's not relevant in OP's example, since the return value of `dynamic_cast<>` isn't an lvalue either.

Answer (score 17):

If similarObject is a smart pointer, this technique is sometimes used to get the reference of a raw pointer, when * has been overloaded.

Comment: `auto_ptr` and the Boost and tr1 smart pointers all have a function for this, `.get()`

Answer (score 1):

Nobody mentioned yet that `similarObject` is an lvalue, whereas `&*similarObject` is an rvalue.

Comment: `&*similarObject` need NOT to be an rvalue. It could be a lvalue as well.

Comment: @Nawaz: Only if you overload the unary `&` operator to return a reference. Which is something you absolutely should not do.