# Does '*(&x)' take more work than 'x'

Tags: c++

Is writing this `*(&x)` in my code any different than `x`?  Or does the compiler make them the same thing?

Comment: What is `x`? Without knowing that your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @DDrmmr `x` is just a variable...

Comment: Well in C we have the following wording in the standard [If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21247407/1708801) as far as I know we don't equivalent wording in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC at least appears to generate the same instructions for both `*(&x)` and just `x` assuming that whatever type `x` is doesn't overload the `&` and `*` operators.

Comment: how can check one what instructions the compiler generates?

Comment: You can use the `-S` flag for GCC, there are also a few websites that are able to do it like http://assembly.ynh.io/

Answer (score 3):

It certainly doesn't help readability.

As long as there's no operator overloading going on it is almost certain that the compiler would generate identical code for the two. Compile to assembly (`-S` in `gcc`) to see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> Is writing this *(&x) in my code any different than x?

They might mean **different** thing if `*` or/and `&` are overloaded operators, else `*(&x)` and `x` mean the same thing, in which case it decreases readability and so you wouldn't like to write that. See this similar topic:

- [Difference between &(*similarObject) and similarObject? Are they not same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958520/difference-between-similarobject-and-similarobject-are-they-not-same)

Hope that helps.